# Output Free Disk Space using grep

Tags: macos, terminal, grep

I'm trying to create a terminal command which outputs the free disk space of the main HDD.
When entering: `diskutil info disk1s4 | grep -o "Free Space:.* GB"`
The result is: `Free Space:         252.3 GB`

I get the correct information but also `Free Space:` which I don't want.

Is there a flag I can set which just shows me the results of the wildcard and not the surrounding text ?

I tried Using `-A 0 -B 0` to limit the lines. 
removing the `-o` flag

The end result should be `252.3 GB`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `awk` instead.

```
diskutil info disk1s4 | awk '/Free Space:.* GB/ {print $3}'
```

Or to get the `GB` at the end.

```
diskutil info disk1s4 | awk '/Free Space:.* GB/ {print $3,$4}'
```